# how do I perform a function on an item in a jquery array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to prepend a single element in a jquery array for example: I wish to prepend an image to the second element in this list.

```
<ul class="works">
    <li>Zero</li>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

I have unsuccessfully tried variations of:

```
$('.error li')[1].prepend("<img class='formHelpLink' src='http://placehold.it/50x50'>");
```

However I just can't get it to work.

Here is a Js fiddle of the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/gpsso478/

Comment: I have just found .eq() which works but I still am not sure, why the original didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method to get jQuery object. When you use `[1]` it gets underlying DOM element and DOm element doesn't have `prepend` method.

Use

```
$('.error li').eq(1).prepend("<img class='formHelpLink' src='http://placehold.it/50x50'>");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cw4ge2jn/0)

Comment: Exactly! Just for the fun of it.. Why doesn't $('.error li').next().append("<img class='formHelpLink' src='http://placehold.it/50x50'>"); work? I thought this would only set one image but it set it all images from next() position and all li's below under the ul.error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use li:eq(1) selector to select second li

```
 $('.works li').prepend("<img class='formHelpLink' src='http://placehold.it/50x50'>");


    $('.error li:eq(1)').prepend("<img class='formHelpLink' src='http://placehold.it/50x50'>");
```